# Retrieve and validate email from firebase on checking forgot password

Tags: java, firebase, android-studio, forgot-password

I have stored the data to firebase as- path: users and parent as the name on signup.but in forgot password, I want to check whether the typed email is present. If it is present I want to send reset link. But when I checked to find whether email id is present it the result is an error.

**Code:**

```
final String email=forgotenteredmail.getEditText().getText().toString().trim();
    rootnode= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    reference=rootnode.getReference("users");
    Query checkuser=reference.orderByChild("name").equalTo(email);

 checkuser.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if(dataSnapshot.exists())
            {

                forgotenteredmail.setError(null);
                forgotenteredmail.setErrorEnabled(false);
                    Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),makeSelection.class);
                    startActivity(intent);


                }
                else
                {
                    forgotenteredmail.setError("Use does not Exist");
                    forgotenteredmail.requestFocus();
                }
            }[enter image description here][1]
       @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

}
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FFBCM.png)

Comment: What do you mean by this line `reference.orderByChild("name").equalTo(email)`? the orderByChild will just arrange the data will not filter it.

Comment: 'Query checkuser=reference.orderByChild("email").equalTo(email)'--------used to fetch email from database and to check whether it is sameas entered email   @DeepakKumar